# Migrating from Postgres RDS to Aurora without changing endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have around 40 micro services that connect to my Postgres RDS database. Now I am considering migrating to Amazon Aurora. Each of the connections connect to the RDS endpoint and modifying that across 40 micro services will mean that there will be quite significant downtime, coordination and stress. I am assuming that there would be a smarter way to do this, where I can somehow keep the endpoint and just redirect it from RDS to Aurora. I have looked into Amazon RDS Proxy, and it would be great to change all the micro services to use that as an endpoint, but it seems like I am adding a lot of complexity for this small purpose.

Researching this did not get me far, which makes me believe that I am missing something obvious, but I don't understand what it is.

Comment: I can't help with RDS proxy but you could read the docs / try it out. I will share one observation that may be interesting though. If I create an RDS Oracle database, delete the DB, and create another Oracle RDS DB the database URL for the second is the same as the first. Of course if I don't delete the first database the second DB URL is different. I wonder if in a new account you could create a PostgresDB, delete it, then create Aurora and see if the endpoint is the same. I doubt it will work, but it shouldn't take long to try.

Comment: The docs for RDS Proxy say it's for one database. I suspect you're going to have to change your microservice configurations. Using RDS Proxy might help availability in future, but I suspect it won't help the migration.

Comment: @Tim The endpoint for Aurora seem to be different than RDS, and they actually contain "aurora" hardcoded into them, it seems.  Like [my_instance_name]-cluster.cluster-cbktrbeczmex.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com

So it does not seem like I could rename it to the endpoint as I used on RDS

Comment: That's annoying, but I think you may just have to accept that you need to change the URL unfortunately. Migration is an exercise.